# Why can't I ping a Docker container from the host when using IPVLAN in L3 mode?

Tags: linux, networking, docker

I've got a docker host with a interface on network 10.0.1.0/24 and ip address 10.0.1.9. I created a docker network as follows:

```
docker network create -d ipvlan \
--subnet=10.0.2.0/24 \
-o host_iface=ens3 \
-o ipvlan_mode=l3 \
ipvlan_net
```

I then create a container as follows:

```
docker run -itd --rm --network ipvlan_net --ip 10.0.2.10 --name test busybox
```

If I create multiple containers each container can ping each other, but no container can ping the host at 10.0.1.9, nor can the host ping the containers. I've searched online but none of the (what little) instruction I found was helpful.

Comment: i can reproduce this behavior, related. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71273149/how-to-connect-additional-network-to-container-with-ipvlan-l3-network

Answer (score 2):

You can't ping the host because this is a security feature present on both macvlan/ipvlan networks.  Traffic originated from the host to containers (and vice-versa) is filtered to enforce a strong network isolation.

If you want to have host-to-container connectivity (and vice-versa), you must manually create an ipvlan subinterface in the default namespace on the host. Try this:

```bash
ip link add ipvl0 link ens3 type ipvlan mode l3
ip link set ipvl0 up
ip addr add 10.0.250.0/24 dev ipvl0
ip route add 10.0.2.0/24 dev ipvl0
```

See this https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/21735#issuecomment-205904902.